# blank string is true or false in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
'' == false // true
' ' == false // true
if ('') {
  // this code is not run
}
if (' ') {
  // this code is run
}
```

As you can see, there are interesting results.
The empty string is treated as `falsy`, as we already know.
However, whitespace strings are treated as `truthy` or `falsy`, depending on the situation.

Comment: The "conversion" to truthy or falsy is not the same as an `==` comparison to `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the link posted in your question about `toBoolean` behavior. Another interesting tidbit;javascript has another comparison operator `===` that checks for value and type

```
'' == false // true
'' === false // false
```

Answer (score 1):

A blank String is false.

```js
console.log(' '==true);
console.log(''==true);
```

This is often the problem with the `==` operator; it attempts to coerce the types of the objects it is comparing to be equal. If you use the `===` operator, it will not attempt type coercion.

```js
console.log(''===false);
```